# Javascript problem, script works 100% only with an alert(); in place ODD

Tags: javascript, json, razor

calling all JavaScript Gurus. I'm going bananas, in the following script if I remove the Alert the code does not work. But I obviously cannot leave a pop up in the middle of my ASP.NET web App

Not that it matters much but this code is in a Index.cshtml that contains a partial called IndexSearch Results.cshtml. Code at the bottom but its just the Javascript below I think is the issue ::

Something is missing I cannot figure it, many thanks for looking...

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/tablesorter")

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('a').each(function () {
                $(this).qtip({
                    content: {
                        text: $(this).next('.tooltiptext')
                    }
                });
            });

            $('#searchButton').click(function () {
                var url = '/SupplyPoint/IndexSearch';

                var data = {
                    searchSPID: $('#SearchSPID').val().toString(),
                    searchPremise: $('#SearchPremise').val().toString()
                };

                $("#ResultsList").load(url, data, function () {
                    $('#LoadingGif').empty(); 
                });


                $('#LoadingGif').empty().html('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading...');

                Init();

            });


            function Init() {

                if ($("#myTable").find("tr").size() > 1) {

                    alert('Without this Alert the Tablesorter does not apply formatting, i.e. no paging, no zebra, nothing just one big list, odd');
                    $("#myTable").tablesorter({ dateFormat: "uk", widgets: ['zebra'], sortList: [[4, 0]] }).tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager") });

                    $('tr').live('click', function (e) {

                        //if not clicking an anchor tag or imag then assume user wants to go to details page
                        if ((!$(e.target).is('a')) && (!$(e.target).is('img')) && (!$(e.target).is('th')) && !(e.target.isTextEdit)) {
                            if ($(this).attr('rowid') != null)
                                window.location = 'SupplyPoint/Details/' + $(this).attr('rowid');
                        }

                    });
                } else {

                    $("#myTable").hide(); $("#pager").hide();
                }

                return false;
            };
        });

    </script>
```

Here is Index.CSHTML:

```
@model IEnumerable<AscendancyCF.Models.SupplyPoint>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<style>
    .tooltiptext {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<h2></h2>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>
                    <img width="50" height="50" src="~/content/images/bPremise.jpg" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Use the Search fields provided to Locate a Premise

                </legend>

                <table class="NoHighlight">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            SSID<br />

                                @Html.TextBox("SearchSPID", string.Empty, new { style = "float:left;width:150px;" })


                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            Premise Name<br />
                            @Html.TextBox("SearchPremise", string.Empty, new { style = "float:left;width:170px;" })
                            <div id="Div1" style="float:left; padding-left:5px;"></div>
                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        </td>
                        @*<td>
                            Effective Start >=<br />
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBox("StartDate")
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Effective End<br />
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBox("EndDate")
                                </div>
                        </td>*@                

                        <td>

                            <a href="#test" class="btn btn-default"  id="searchButton" >Search</a>

                            <div class="tooltiptext">
                                Key less by entering only part of a Search String <b>i.e.</b> key <i>Garage</i> to find <i>all premises containing this text</i> quickly
                            </div>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="LoadingGif"></div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>

            <div id="ResultsList" style="clear:both;">
                @Html.Partial("IndexSearchResults")

            </div>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/tablesorter")

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('a').each(function () {
                $(this).qtip({
                    content: {
                        text: $(this).next('.tooltiptext')
                    }
                });
            });

            $('#searchButton').click(function () {
                var url = '/SupplyPoint/IndexSearch';

                var data = {
                    searchSPID: $('#SearchSPID').val().toString(),
                    searchPremise: $('#SearchPremise').val().toString()
                };

                $("#ResultsList").load(url, data, function () {
                    $('#LoadingGif').empty(); 
                });


                $('#LoadingGif').empty().html('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading...');

                Init();

            });


            function Init() {

                if ($("#myTable").find("tr").size() > 1) {

                    alert('Without this Alert the Tablesorter does not apply formatting, i.e. no paging, no zebra, nothing just one big list, odd');
                    $("#myTable").tablesorter({ dateFormat: "uk", widgets: ['zebra'], sortList: [[4, 0]] }).tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager") });

                    $('tr').live('click', function (e) {

                        //if not clicking an anchor tag or imag then assume user wants to go to details page
                        if ((!$(e.target).is('a')) && (!$(e.target).is('img')) && (!$(e.target).is('th')) && !(e.target.isTextEdit)) {
                            if ($(this).attr('rowid') != null)
                                window.location = 'SupplyPoint/Details/' + $(this).attr('rowid');
                        }

                    });
                } else {

                    $("#myTable").hide(); $("#pager").hide();
                }

                return false;
            };
        });


</script>
```

}

and here is IndexSearchResults.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<AscendancyCF.Models.SupplyPoint>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p><h5><div id="noRecords">Your search returned @Model.Count() items</div></h5></p>
<table class="tablesorter" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th></th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SPID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SupplyPointName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GazateerRef)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SupplyPointEffectiveDateTime)
            </th>
            <th>
                Premise Type
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr rowid="@item.SupplyPointId">
        <td>
            <a href="/SupplyPoint/Edit/@item.SupplyPointId" id="Edit"><img src="~/Content/images/edit.png" id="imgEdit" alt='Edit Details' title='Edit Details'></a>


        </td>


        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SPID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupplyPointName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GazateerRef)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupplyPointEffectiveDateTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupplyPointType.SupplyPointTypeName)
        </td>

    </tr>

}
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="pager" id="pager">

    <form>
        <img src="~/Content/Images/first.gif" id="iFirst" class="first" />
        <img src="~/Content/Images/prev.gif" class="prev" />
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay" />
        <img src="~/Content/Images/next.gif" class="next" />
        <img src="~/Content/Images/last.gif" class="last" />
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="500">500</option> 
        </select> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you declare a tablesorter instance on startup, not in the click function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.load` is asynchronous, so it will return before the content is loaded. In the `Init` function, you are trying to use the content before it has been loaded. The `alert()` is making it succeed, since it allows the content to be loaded.

Instead of calling `Init()` immediately after the `load()` call, you should move it inside the callback.

```
$('#searchButton').click(function () {
    var url = '/SupplyPoint/IndexSearch';

    var data = {
        searchSPID: $('#SearchSPID').val().toString(),
        searchPremise: $('#SearchPremise').val().toString()
    };

    $("#ResultsList").load(url, data, function () {
        $('#LoadingGif').empty(); 
        Init(); // <--- Here
    });


    $('#LoadingGif').empty().html('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading...');
});
```

Comment: Amazing you are BANG on with that!!! Works, too close to see it I guess - off for a beer now