# Bootstrap 3 MVC4 Razor, after reloading a Partial View ToolTips fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

If my Tooltip is not HTML format, after the partial re-loads it becomes a standard tooltip with no formatting. But if I have it in HTML mode it goes completely

All my Javascript is in the main View, i've tried a few things already, many in fact. But now need to step back and ask for advice

Here is the HTML that defines the Partial, this DIV is part of a larger detail View but i'm only showing the relevant code for brevity

```
<div class="modal fade" id="PricingTool" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4>
                    Premise @Model.Premise.CoreSPID is @ViewData["MeteredStatus"] & contains <span class="badge">@Model.Premise.SupplyPoints.Count()</span> Spid(s)

                </h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        From <input type="text" value="@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))" id="from" class="datepicker">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        To <input type="text" value="@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))" id="to" class="datepicker">
                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="LoadingGif"></div>
            <div id="ResultsList" style="clear:both;">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("_DetailsPricing", Model.Premise);}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <a class="btn btn-primary" id="RefreshBtn">Re-Calculate</a>
                <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript from the main View :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("[rel=show-tooltip]").tooltip({ html: true });

    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });


    //$("#myTable").hide();
    $("#pager").hide();




    function Init() {

        if ($("#myTable").find("tr").size() > 1) {


            $("#myTable").tablesorter({ dateFormat: "uk", widgets: ['zebra'], sortList: [[2, 0]] }).tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager") });


        } else {

            $("#myTable").hide(); $("#pager").hide();
        }

        return false;
    };


    $('.show-tooltip').each(function (e) {
        var p = $(this).parent();
        if (p.is('td')) {
            /* if your tooltip is on a <td>, transfer <td>'s padding to wrapper */
            $(this).css('padding', p.css('padding'));
            p.css('padding', '0 0');
        }
        $(this).tooltip({
            toggle: 'toolip',
            placement: 'bottom'
        });
    });



    $("#RefreshBtn").click(function () {
        ReloadPartial();
    });



    function ReloadPartial() {



        var url = '/SupplyPoint/PricingUpdate';

        var data = {
            StartDate: $('#from').val(),
            EndDate: $('#to').val(),
            SupplyPointId: $('#SupplyPointId').val().toString()
        };

        $("#ResultsList").load(url, data, function () {
            $('#LoadingGif').empty();

        });

        $('#LoadingGif').empty().html('<img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" width=31 height=31 alt="Loading image" />');




        return false;
    };
});
```

Finally - here is a code extract from the partial cshtml thats showing tooltip. I've left the rest out because its not relevant, just looping the model passed in, there is no Javascript here yet. Here is one part that shows tooltip perfectly - albeit after reload its lost

```
                            <div class="show-tooltip" data-html="true" data-original-title="@pricing.VolumetricChargeWorking">


                                    <div>&pound;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pricing.VolumetricCharge)</div>
```

Comment: If I add Javascript Alerts to the end of my ReloadPartial() function in main view it fixes things. But I cannot have alerts in my application

Comment: Solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193746/javascript-proble-script-works-100-only-with-an-alert-in-place-odd

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193746/javascript-proble-script-works-100-only-with-an-alert-in-place-odd

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code from your main view into your partial view :

```
$("[rel=show-tooltip]").tooltip({ html: true });
```

That way each time the partial is rendered it will initialize your tooltips.

Comment: When I try this I get the same result, it only works first time around. Your suggestion makes sense to me - thanks but i'm not sure why it does not work

Comment: Try this in your partial instead: $(".show-tooltip").tooltip({ html: true });